# Core Data inheritance : How To Get Entity Subclasses at runtime?

Tags: objective-c, inheritance, core-data, entity, subclass

I got the following Core Data Model :

ParentEntity (abstract)

- ChildAEntity having ParentEntity as parent
- ChildBEntity having ParentEntity as parent

How could I get at run time an Array of my subentities (or subclasses names) ?

### *EDIT 1

Ok I think I got a solution but not sure. I got way to retrieve subclasses of my parent class. Perhaps I should just make my children classes inherit of my parent class and I will retreive my subclasses. But what is strange to me is that xCode do not generate inheritance when an entity has a parent but mogenerator do...

As me do you think that most of the time, if a got an entity A and a subentity B, generated classes ClassB should inherit classA ?

### *EDIT 2

Question about retrieving subentities of an entity from the core data model is still open. I 'm curious to know how it could be done...

Here is how to get subclasses from an objective C class.
http://cocoawithlove.com/2010/01/getting-subclasses-of-objective-c-class.html

Comment: There is a long and interesting discussion of this on this page: [FindingAllSubclassesOfAClass:CocoaDev](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?FindingAllSubclassesOfAClass)

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume you have an entity description 'e' then you can get the subentities by calling 'e.subentities' which returns an array of entity descriptions. Each entity description knows its managed object class name. Now you can combine this:

```
NSEntityDescription *e = ...;
NSArray *subentities = e.subentities;
NSArray *managedObjectClassNames = [subentities valueForKey:@"managedObjectClassName"];

// managedObjectClassNames contains the class names.
```

Or you could do it without KVC-magic:

```
NSEntityDescription *e = ...;
NSArray *subentities = e.subentities;
NSMutableArray *managedObjectClassNames = [NSMutableArray array];
for(NSEntityDescription *subentity in subentities) {
    NSString *managedObjectClassName = subentity.managedObjectClassName;
    if(managedObjectClassName != nil) {
        [managedObjectClassNames addObject:managedObjectClassName];
    }
}

// managedObjectClassNames contains the class names.
```